# I'm unable to understand below c# code fragment

Tags: c#

I only have this part of the code. I'm unable to make sense is "next" another method of ptr or is it the random.next method. Just want to know if this is a common code fragment used by experts.

```
Node mystery(Node ptr) {
    Node temp;
    Node previous = null;
    while (ptr != null) {
        temp = ptr.next;
        ptr.next = previous;
        previous = ptr;
        ptr = temp;
    }
    return previous;
}
```

Comment: Click on `next` then hit `F12`.

Comment: This looks like a pretty standard linked list where each `Node` has a pointer to the one after it, which is commonly called `next`.

Comment: `next` cannot be a *method* - it has to be a *property* because you assign a value to it

Comment: @SirRufo my guess would be a field :)

Comment: @MarcGravell Well naming conventions are absent here - look at the method name `mystery`

Comment: this *looks* like it is reversing a linked list? if so: sure, it might be used occasionally; not an every day thing, by an stretch; and to be honest, you *probably shouldn't* write your own list/collection/etc types very often

Comment: @MarcGravell I don't think it's a doubly linked list, there are no managements of *previous* node. However, I'm sure it's reversing the order of the list

Comment: @Cid fair enough

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reverse-a-linked-list/ <- Has a nice animation showing how the code works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can *execute* the logic steps by steps, using your debugger or a piece of paper with a pen.

This looks like a [linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list). Each node pointing to the next one, the last note pointing to `null`

```
head                    tail
+---+       +---+       +---+
|"A"| next  |"B"| next  |"C"| next
|   |------>|   |------>|   |------> null
+---+       +---+       +---+
```

`while (ptr != null) {` will loop until the *current* node is `null`

The code inside the while scope is a typical swap. Let's execute it steps by steps, considering `ptr` is the node containing `"A"`, like above

```
temp = ptr.next;
```

Now, `temp` is poiting to the next node.

```
 ptr
  |
  v
+---+       +---+       +---+
|"A"| next  |"B"| next  |"C"| next
|   |------>|   |------>|   |------> null
+---+       +---+       +---+
              ^
              |
            temp
```

---

```
ptr.next = previous;
```

Now, `ptr.next` is pointing to `previous` which was initialized to null. `ptr` is now *de-linked* from the list

```
 ptr
  |
  v
+---+             | +---+       +---+
|"A"| next        | |"B"| next  |"C"| next
|   |------> null | |   |------>|   |------> null
+---+             | +---+       +---+
                  |   ^
                  |   |
                    temp
```

---

```
previous = ptr;
```

Both `ptr` and `previous` are pointing to the same node

```
 ptr
  |
  v
+---+             | +---+       +---+
|"A"| next        | |"B"| next  |"C"| next
|   |------> null | |   |------>|   |------> null
+---+             | +---+       +---+
  ^               |   ^
  |               |   |
previous             temp
```

---

```
ptr = temp;
```

Now, both `ptr` and `temp` are pointing to the same node

```
                     ptr
                      |
                      v
+---+             | +---+       +---+
|"A"| next        | |"B"| next  |"C"| next
|   |------> null | |   |------>|   |------> null
+---+             | +---+       +---+
  ^               |   ^
  |               |   |
previous             temp
```

Since `ptr != null` is true, the loop continue :

```
temp = ptr.next;

                     ptr
                      |
                      v
+---+             | +---+       +---+
|"A"| next        | |"B"| next  |"C"| next
|   |------> null | |   |------>|   |------> null
+---+             | +---+       +---+
  ^               |               ^
  |               |               |
previous                        temp
```

---

```
ptr.next = previous;
```

Now, the next item of the current node is the one saved previously (the `"A"` node) :

```
 ptr
  |
  v
+---+        +---+             | +---+
|"B"| next   |"A"| next        | |"C"| next
|   |------> |   |------> null | |   |------> null
+---+        +---+             | +---+
               ^               |   ^
               |                   |
            previous              temp
```

---

```
previous = ptr;

 ptr
  |
  v
+---+        +---+             | +---+
|"B"| next   |"A"| next        | |"C"| next
|   |------> |   |------> null | |   |------> null
+---+        +---+             | +---+
  ^                            |   ^
  |                                |
previous                         temp
```

---

```
ptr = temp;

                                  ptr
                                   |
                                   v
+---+        +---+             | +---+
|"B"| next   |"A"| next        | |"C"| next
|   |------> |   |------> null | |   |------> null
+---+        +---+             | +---+
  ^                            |   ^
  |                                |
previous                         temp
```

Since `ptr != null` is true, the loop continues and the same logic is applied :

```
temp = ptr.next;

                                  ptr
                                   |
                                   v
+---+        +---+             | +---+
|"B"| next   |"A"| next        | |"C"| next
|   |------> |   |------> null | |   |------> null
+---+        +---+          ^  | +---+          ^
  ^                         |  |                |
  |                         |                   |
previous                    +-----------------temp
```

---

```
ptr.next = previous;

 ptr
  |
  v
+---+        +---+        +---+
|"C"| next   |"B"| next   |"A"| next
|   |------> |   |------> |   |------> null
+---+        +---+        +---+          ^
               ^                         |
               |                         |
           previous                     temp
```

---

```
previous = ptr;

 ptr
  |
  v
+---+        +---+        +---+
|"C"| next   |"B"| next   |"A"| next
|   |------> |   |------> |   |------> null
+---+        +---+        +---+         ^
  ^                                     |
  |                                     |
previous                               temp
```

---

```
ptr = temp;

                                       ptr
                                        |
+---+        +---+        +---+         |
|"C"| next   |"B"| next   |"A"| next    v
|   |------> |   |------> |   |------> null
+---+        +---+        +---+         ^
  ^                                     |
  |                                     |
previous                               temp
```

Now, `while (ptr != null)` is false. The loop ends and `previous`, which is the **new head** is returned.

**This method reverse the order of a linked list and returns the head.**

Answer (score 0):

Usually Node object has a value (e.g of type int) and another property that holds the next node

```
public class Node{
 public int Value {get; set;}
 public Node Next {get; set;}
 //...
}
```

For example here the next node of `n1` is `n2` node

[image]

```
Node n1=new Node(5);
Node n2=new Node(2);
n1.Next=n2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You code reversing a single linked list

It's just another example of reversing a single linked list:
(see [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reverse-a-linked-list/) for more details)

```
// C# program for reversing the linked list 
using System; 

class GFG { 
    static void Main(string[] args) 
    { 
        LinkedList list = new LinkedList(); 
        list.AddNode(new LinkedList.Node(85)); 
        list.AddNode(new LinkedList.Node(15)); 
        list.AddNode(new LinkedList.Node(4)); 
        list.AddNode(new LinkedList.Node(20)); 

        // List before reversal 
        Console.WriteLine("Given linked list:"); 
        list.PrintList(); 

        // Reverse the list 
        list.ReverseList(); 

        // List after reversal 
        Console.WriteLine("Reversed linked list:"); 
        list.PrintList(); 
    } 
} 

class LinkedList { 
    Node head; 

    public class Node { 
        public int data; 
        public Node next; 

        public Node(int d) 
        { 
            data = d; 
            next = null; 
        } 
    } 

    // function to add a new node at 
    // the end of the list 
    public void AddNode(Node node) 
    { 
        if (head == null) 
            head = node; 
        else { 
            Node temp = head; 
            while (temp.next != null) { 
                temp = temp.next; 
            } 
            temp.next = node; 
        } 
    } 

    // function to reverse the list 
    public void ReverseList() 
    { 
        Node prev = null, current = head, next = null; 
        while (current != null) { 
            next = current.next; 
            current.next = prev; 
            prev = current; 
            current = next; 
        } 
        head = prev; 
    } 

    // function to print the list data 
    public void PrintList() 
    { 
        Node current = head; 
        while (current != null) { 
            Console.Write(current.data + " "); 
            current = current.next; 
        } 
        Console.WriteLine(); 
    } 
}
```